# How could I import the rows with matched value on another sheet on Google spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, formula, spreadsheet

I have one sheet to record the raw data. 
Now, I want to make another is for picking up the validated.

My Raw table is like the following

```
==Sheet A==

1--John--1992--Attend
2--Mary--1990--
3--Jam--1920--Attend
4--Mark--4820--
5--Aaron--4710--Attend
6--Chris--6893--Attend
```

And I expect having another sheet for picking up the "Attend" and export like this

```
==Sheet B ==

1--John--1992
2--Jam--1920
3--Aaron--4710
4--Chris--6893
```

So I tried this

```
=INDEX('Sheet A'!A1:B6,Match("Attend",'Sheet A'!C2:C6))
```

But the formula I wrote only exported the first row

```
==Sheet B ==

1--John--1992
```

How could I get the rest data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Filter()` formula is best fit for this case. Try-

```
=FILTER('Sheet A'!A1:C6,'Sheet A'!C1:C6="Attend")
```

[image]